# EditText Background color opacity android

Tags: java, android

I am giving user to change background color of edit textview. I want also give user to chance for set opacity of color. My edit text XML code is like below

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_quotes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:shadowRadius="0"
    android:text="Text" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText" />
```

Let me know if someone have idea to set opacity of change background color of this view.  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this alpha, it gives you the opacity, programmatically

```
youredittext.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

Comment: I want it programmatically. Let me know if you have idea for it.

Comment: Hi ! its showing error called Value must be >0.0 and <1.0 (was 4)

Comment: try giving value as 0.4

Comment: now setAlfa (float) in View cannot be applied to double

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154816/discussion-between-priya-and-sunil-p).

Comment: glad to help you, don't mind to upvote If the answer was useful